# Hide table and container in jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to show no data label where is no data display and want to show table where there is data.

Now in this code when I try this show that when there is no data this show table headers and container where as i want to hide this code.

**updated code**

```
 success: function (result) {
         // var myData = JSON.parse(result.d);
          //console.log(JSON.parse(result.d));
          **alert("ab");**
          if (result == null && result.empty && result.length==0) {
          //if (myData == null && Object.keys(myData).length == 0) {
              **alert("de");**
              $("#<%=Label4.ClientID%>").text("No Chart");
              $("#tabledata").hide();
              $("#container").hide();
              $("#cont").hide();
              return;
            }

            strarr = result.d;
            var myarr = strarr;
            Drewchart(myarr);
            $("#tabledata").show();
            $("#container").show();
            $("#<%=Label4.ClientID%>").hide();
        },
```

when i check f12 then console show like that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xtwmt.png

this show null and empty where as i also set condition and when i build my code alert **ab** is call but alert **de** is not display so this means code not going under **if condition**

**markup**

```
<table id="tabledata" cellspacing="0"  class="inner_table">

   </table>

 <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />


   <div id="container">
  </div>

   <div id="cont">
  </div>
```

any solution

Comment: Is your code executing this line `$("#tabledata").hide();`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put a property `NoData` and set it to `true` when there is no data in your `json` at server side and return it to client. Then check for this property:

```
success: function (result) {

      var myData = JSON.parse(result.d);
      if(myData.NoData){
        // Show label and hide table
        $("#tabledata, #containter, #cont").hide();
      }
      else{
            // Show table and data
      }
  }
```

Comment: @user6628729 check

Comment: It seems correct. Debug and check if the program is entering in the right `if`.